# Does a graph always have a minimum spanning tree that is binary?

Tags: graphs, binary-trees, spanning-trees, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a graph and I need to find a minimum spanning tree to a given graph. What is to be done so that the output obtained is a binary tree?

Comment: I just need to know if it is possible or not. I have done some digging though. I just want to know if there is any way to generate a spanning tree which is binary as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing to be done: for instance, let $S_k$ denote the [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)) with $k$ leaves. The graph $S_k$ has a unique spanning tree (which is $S_k$ itself), and it has a vertex with degree exactly $k$.

In fact, the general problem of [finding a degree-constrained minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree-constrained_spanning_tree) is NP-complete.